RHF Field array duplicating fields
I'm experiencing an issue with RHF and the field array feature. I've been using it by the past without any issue. But today it's quiet different and I'm stuck.
Here is the issue:
When I'm starting filling on of the field of my fields, RHF recreate this field using a new UUID. Check this screenshot:

The first log shows my default values for this field array. An object with null string every where. When I start typing, in the field value for example, RHF recreates another field, with undefined everywhere and my typed value goes here.
Here is my code:
const SegmentForm = () => {
  const { control, getValues, watch } = useFormContext();
  const { fields, append, remove} = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'filters'
  });

  watch('filters');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(getValues().filters));
  console.log(getValues().filters);
  return (
    <Stack gap={4} mt={2} mb={4}>
      <Field.Text name='name' label='Name' InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />
      <Field.Text
        multiline
        name='description'
        label='Description'
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
      />

      <Stack justifyContent='space-between' direction='row'>
        <Typography>Filters</Typography>
        <Button
          onClick={() =>
            append({
              field: '',
              operator: '',
              value: ''
            })
          }
          variant='contained'
          startIcon={<Iconify icon='mingcute:add-line' />}
        >
          New filter
        </Button>
      </Stack>

      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        const selectedField = getValues('filters')[field?.id]?.field;
        const subFields = FIELDS.find((e) => e.id === selectedField)?.values;

        return (
          <Stack key={field.id} spacing={4}>
            <Stack spacing={4} justifyContent='space-between' direction='row' alignItems='center'>
              <Field.Select name={`filters.${field.id}.field`} label='Field'>
                {FIELDS.map((option) => (
                  <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                    {option.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Field.Select>
              {getValues('filters')?.length > 1 && (
                <Box>
                  <IconButton color='inherit' onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                    <Iconify icon='solar:trash-bin-trash-bold' />
                  </IconButton>
                </Box>
              )}
            </Stack>

            <Stack direction='row' spacing={4}>
              <Field.Select name={`filters.${field.id}.operator`} label='Operator'>
                {OPERATOR.map((option) => (
                  <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                    {option.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Field.Select>
              {!subFields && (
                <Field.Text
                  name={`filters.${field.id}.value`}
                  label='Value'
                  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                />
              )}
              {!!subFields?.length && (
                <Field.Select name={`filters.${field.id}.value`} label='Value'>
                  {subFields.map((option) => (
                    <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                      {option.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Field.Select>
              )}
            </Stack>
            {index !== getValues('filters')?.length - 1 && <Divider />}
          </Stack>
        );
      })}
    </Stack>
  );
};

I'm probably doing something wrong, and I need you help !

After some testing from sratch I've seen my mistake. I used field.id value in the name of the input. This must be the index of the map. field.id must only be used in the key prop of the first node.
 <Field.Select name={`filters.${index}.value`} label='Value'>
   {subFields.map((option) => (
     <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
       {option.label}
     </MenuItem>
   ))}
 </Field.Select>

